# Counting page reloads

Tags: javascript

I think this is impossible, but I'll ask our community of wizards, maybe someone has a trick.

A client is wants to trigger an event on my js injection platform when someone has reloaded the page more than twice. He refuses to either set a value on a cookie onbeforeonload or to have something on the server side that can count.

Anyone know of a way of counting page reloads on the client side?

Comment: `localStorage` or `IP` maybe

Comment: A `cookie` _is_ a sort of local storage thats in the hands of the client and entirely on the client side... If your client is adament on not using cookies for _some_ reason, then you might have to go back and tell them that _this is exactly why cookies exist_. That, and tracking you everywhere you go.

Comment: localStorage is a possibility, but I doubt he'll like that more than cookies. What's the IP idea?

Comment: May be passing a parameter say reloadCount in URL, then access this in javascript.

Comment: @AsinusRex — I think you have an X-Y problem. Finding a solution that will satisfy the client is going to be hard unless they explain why the solutions you've come up with already are unsatisfactory.

Comment: @Utkarsh: If I hit the "Reload" button, you can't change the URL in response to that.

Comment: Sorry, seems I was mistaken. EU cookie law will affect any clientside storage that is not necessary for operation of your site, so yeah, if that is the basis of your client's complaint, you cannot do it without the user's consent. In any way.

Comment: Stupid hack. I don't recommend it. http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/stackoverflow/31607773/

Comment: I think @Utkarsh may have something here. Maybe I can ask the customer to have his code go to the same URL with a different hash instead of reloading. Thanks a bunch, all!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`performance.navigation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation) can be used to distinguish between navigation, history navigation and page reload.

Since you want to know whether the page was refreshed twice, some form of persistency is required because the browser does not keep track of the number of page reloads. For this purpose, the [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries) seems most sensible, because its state is tied to the page instance.

For example (demo showing number of reloads: https://robwu.nl/s/reloadCount.html):

```js
// On load:
var state = history.state || {};
var reloadCount = state.reloadCount || 0;
if (performance.navigation.type === 1) { // Reload
    state.reloadCount = ++reloadCount;
    history.replaceState(state, null, document.URL);
} else if (reloadCount) {
    delete state.reloadCount;
    reloadCount = 0;
    history.replaceState(state, null, document.URL);
}
if (reloadCount >= 2) {
    // Now, do whatever you want...
    alert('The page was reloaded more than twice!');
}
```

I've tested that the demo works in the following browsers:

- Safari 8+
- Chrome 14+ (probably earlier as well, I didn't bother testing 13-)
- Opera 15+
- Firefox 7+
- Internet Explorer 9+

If you need to support older browsers (that do not support the `performance` API), then you could fall back to updating the history state with a timestamp upon unload, and check whether the timestamp (e.g. `Date.now()`) in `history.state` is close to the current time upon load.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly what I was looking for.